# updateChildValues: not saving all data

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A user enters a post with some tags. The tags come back as an array and I'm supposed to check if the tag already exist or not and use a tagID to write it to the post database so that tags relate to post (see below). whats happening now is only the last tagID is being recorded to the database not all of them

```
for item in tags {

    ref.child("tags").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.childSnapshotForPath(item.lowercaseString).exists() {
            let tagKey = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath(item.lowercaseString).value as! String
            self.saveTagID(tagKey, postKey: Postkey, UID: userID)

        } else {
            let tagKey = self.ref.child("tags").childByAutoId().key
            let tagUpdate = ["/tags/\(item.lowercaseString)": tagKey]
            self.ref.updateChildValues(tagUpdate)

            self.saveTagID(tagKey, postKey: Postkey, UID: userID)

        }
    })
}

func saveTagID(tagID: String, postKey: String, UID: String){

    let postTag = [tagID: true]
    print("post tag\(postTag)")
    ref.updateChildValues(["posts/\(postKey)/tagIDs": postTag,
        "user-posts/\(UID)/\(postKey)/tagIDs": postTag])
}
```

This is what the database looks like. In the tagIDs there should be more than just one if there is more than just one tag

```
{
    "posts": {
        "-KNlBs1EC6tkfLA2y4Sc": {
            "author": "Michele",
            "post": "Hello human",
            "tagIDs": {
                "-KNlBs76y5I0KDV1OXS_": true
            },
            "tagNames": "test, hope this works",
            "uid": "QGacTE84GBSC7uuN4wemxCdHXWo2"
        },
        "-KNlCB1CACxXPLpYc5ql": {
            "author": "Michele",
            "post": "You're my only hope",
            "tagIDs": {
                "-KNlCB723ScwIhYDuwRn": true
            },
            "tagNames": "help, Obi wan",
            "uid": "QGacTE84GBSC7uuN4wemxCdHXWo2"
        }
    },
    "tags": {
        "help": "-KNlCB71o5L2PhdQdl62",
        "hope this works": "-KNlBs76y5I0KDV1OXS_",
        "obi wan": "-KNlCB723ScwIhYDuwRn",
        "test": "-KNlBs7509HQ29waf8Ms"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to do 'ref.updateChildValues(["posts/\(postKey)/tagIDs/\(tagID)": true' instead of 'ref.updateChildValues(["posts/\(postKey)/tagIDs": postTag'

Comment: @AndréKool yup that worked thank you!